# A Date object capable of storing microseconds

Tags: java

I'm looking for a Date object capable of storing down to microsecond granularity, does anyone know of one? The standard `Date` object only stores down to milliseconds (I know that this is a platform limitation) and I could get around this by wrapping a `Date` plus a fractional quantity in a custom class. However I was hoping to avoid having to write one with the appropriate calculations etc. I need to parse a `boost::ptime` timestamp in Java and not loose the precision...

Comment: Use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: FYI, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes such as [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSR-310](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/) is in alpha stage, but may be useful to you anyway. (Unfortunately it's predecessor, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), only stores as far as milliseconds.)

[`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) *stores* values down to nanoseconds, but doesn't help in terms of calculations. What calculations do you need to perform?

Comment: Well, primarily differences, but I guess I could work around that by working with the totals (microseconds)...

Comment: Thanks for that JSR, it is indeed interesting, I'll keep an eye on that. The `sql.Timestamp` is about the same as what I guess I need to create anyway - I guess I could wrap that...

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes support a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), more than enough for your [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class is the basic building-block class in java.time, representing a moment in the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of up to nanoseconds. That means up to nine digits of a decimal fraction. The `Z` on the end is short for Zulu and means UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-01-12T12:34:56.123456789Z" );
```

Note that due to a legacy implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html), in Java 8 the current moment is captured only up to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Remedied in Java 9 with a fresh implementation of `Clock`.

## Parsing a string

As for your mention of "boost" "ptime", call the boost routine `std::string to_iso_extended_string(ptime)` to generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format. That string can be parsed as a `LocalDateTime` since the boost code neglects to include any offset-from-UTC or time zone info.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-01-12T12:34:56.123456789" ) ;
```

## Parsing a long

If you happen to have a number of microseconds as a count from the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of beginning of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), you can convert that into an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

The `Instant` class has handy static methods for converting from a [count of whole seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-), from a [count of whole seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-), or from a [count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-). But no such methods for a count of microseconds or nanoseconds.

As a workaround, we can define a `Duration` and add it to the epoch reference date already defined as a constant. We can instantiate a `Duration` as a number of nanoseconds. To get nanoseconds, we multiply your microseconds by a thousand. Note the use of 64-bit `long` rather than 32-bit `int`. Also note the `L` appended to integer literal.

```
long micros = 1_474_457_086_337_977L ;
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( micros * 1_000L );  
Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH.plus( duration );
```

> instant.toString():  2016-09-21T11:24:46.337977Z

Comment: Thanks for your response, I migrated to Java 8 once it became available and now use the new time functionality. This question is from `11 ... :)

Comment: FYI for those not yet using Java 8: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the   [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. And further adapted to Android in the  [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such a class in Java but you could create a decorator class owing a Date and an additional field to store microseconds and override/create a few methods to take them into account.

My only contribution in this answer is to acknowledge your intuition and point you to the decorator pattern.

Comment: That is exactly what the `java.sql.Timestamp` class does. But this is a hack, a poor design. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque No it isn't. `Timestamp' *extends* `Date`.

Comment: @EJP To quote the class doc of Timestamp: “This type is a composite of a java.util.Date and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the java.util.Date component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate.” … “it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date”. These quotes make my point that (a) an additional field is added, and (b) this is a hack, a subclass that pretends to not be a subclass. `Timestamp` *does* extend `Date` but you are supposed to pretend it does not. A poor design and a hack.

Comment: @BasilBourque To quote the class doc of `Timestamp`: `extends java.util.Date`. QED.

Comment: @EJP You are missing the point that the doc tells you that you should ignore that inheritance and always treat `Timestamp` as if it does *not* inherit from `Date`. This is no secret conspiracy on my part: it is right there in the `Timestamp` class doc. The java.time classes were invented for a reason: the old date-time classes are a mess. The old classes were a valiant first effort in an industry that had ignored this crucial problem of date-time handling for too long. But that effort fell short. Thus was born Joda-Time and then java.time. Sun accepts this, as does Oracle, and so should you.