# Convert microseconds string to date in Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala

how to convert timestamp(in microseconds) string to date in Java/Scala.
My goal is to compare two timestamps and find the differences between them.
I'm using java 8 and example Timestamp string is 1474457086337977.
I would like to convert this into Date or Timestamp instance.

Comment: Why don't you just get current date and time?

Comment: @NoOne because the current date and time is not going to help you get the difference between two timestamps, like the question clearly explains :/

Comment: Actually I will get tis timestamp from external resource as part of my data and i will need to compare this timestamp and do some logic.

Comment: I really dont understand , why this question is down voted. if you feel the answer is quit simple , pls provide the answer else quote the reason for down voting.

Comment: as far as I remember every date lib has a way to create Dates from milliseconds (as long), so you just need to parse the string to long, and then create the Date (I recommend joda DateTime - it has nice methods to compare dates)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 my timestamp string is in microseconds not in milliseconds

Comment: ok, but 1 microsecond = 0.001 milliseconds...can't you convert it?

Comment: @BDR Down-votes may be due this topic having been asked and answered many many many times before on Stack Overflow but you did not bother to search before posting.

Comment: And a duplicate of this and many more: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24168492/642706

Comment: Regarding the microseconds issue, another duplicate: [A Dare object capable of storing microseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7242104/642706)

Comment: I re-opened this Question. Upon further research I could not find any Question that directly asked about instantiating date-time values with a count-from-epoch of microseconds. The linked questions discuss various related issues, but do not directly address instantiating from a number of microseconds. And I added an answer to do so with java.time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what about converting those microseconds to milliseconds and then just create a timestamp object?

```
long microsecs = 1474457086337977L;
long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(microsecs, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(millis);
```

Wouldn't that work?

**--Edit**

To address the comments left in the answer:

**About Java 8's new Date Time API**

First, since you mention that you're using Java 8 I totally agree that a better approach would be to use the new Java 8 Date/Time API. However, this is a luxury you don't always have even when working with Java 8 because you may still be interacting with an old API still using the old Java Date/Time classes, or simply because the rest of your API still uses them and you don't want to start mixing things.

It is not clear in your question if you already know this, you seem to be sure that you want to use either `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` and I didn't question that, I just worked around the parameters of your question.

Clearly the new Java date/time APIs are much better than the old ones, but there are millions of lines of code out there still using the old APIs and they work. Yet again I thought that was out of the scope of the answer and it seems you already have other good answers here to address that.

**About Possible Data Loss**

One comment mentions that the answer might run into data loss. I think in Java all integer arithmetic is subject to potential underflow or overflow. My mistake is probably not have mentioned it.

It is true that `TimeUnit.convert` method might end up causing overflows or underflows in certain scenarios. It is documented in the method.

- A nanosecond is one billionth of a second (1/1000000000)
- A microsecond is one millionth of a second (1/1000000).
- A millisecond is one thousandth of a second (1/1000)

Which means that, once expressed as a long, a millisecond number should be a much smaller number than a microsecond one, right?

The formula used by `TimeUnit.convert` is as follows

```
final long MICROS = 1000000L;
final long MILLIS = 1000L;

long microsecs = 1474457086337977L;
long millisecs = microsecs / (MICROS / MILLIS)
```

Which means you would run into data loss only if your microseconds are really small numbers e.g. if you had less than 1,000 microseconds. You should validate your code never goes into a scenario like this.

One comment left in this answer argues that the right answer should probably use nanoseconds, but then again a nanosecond long value would be a much bigger number than your microseconds and so, during conversions to nanoseconds you might still run into overflows.

For example, think what would happen if you had `Long.MAX_VALUE` microseconds, how could you convert that to nanoseconds using just Java long arithmetic without an overflow given that nanoseconds are supposed to be a much bigger number than your `Long.MAX_VALUE` microseconds?

My point being that regardless of you using Java 8 Date Time or legacy Java Date Time APIs you need a `long` value representing an instant in the time line, but that `long` has limitations in regards to how far in the past or how far in the future you can go, and when you do conversions between units, that arithmetic is subject to underflow and overflow and there's no way around it and you should be aware of that to avoid very nasty bugs.

Once more, I thought that was a given and outside the scope of the question and I bring it up only because I got some downvotes for this omission.

Comment: Know that [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is a bad hack of a class, extending `java.util.Date` but pretending not to. Recommended for use where necessary to transit data in/out of database, but not recommended for business logic. This class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. The java.time classes can handle [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (even finer than microseconds).

Comment: This Answer's code **results in data loss**, truncating microseconds to milliseconds. While using java.time is a better route, if you insist on this approach, then you may want to do the additional math to set this `Timestamp` object's nano field by calling [`setNanos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#setNanos(int)).

Comment: @BasilBourque I doubt that there is way to do integer/long arithmetic in Java without running in overflow or underflow at some point. My mistake was probably not mentioning it. As far as I can tell nanoseconds conversions would be subject to the same precision problems.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.EPOCH.plus( 
    Duration.ofNanos( 
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos( 
            Long.parse( "1474457086337977" ) ) ) )
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes support a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), more than enough for your [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

## Parsing a string of a number

Parse the string as a `long` to get a count of microseconds from the epoch.

```
long micros = Long.parse( "1474457086337977" );
```

And of course you can always use an integer literal. Note the `L` appended to integer literal.

```
long micros = 1_474_457_086_337_977L ;
```

## Converting a long into `Instant`

We want to transform that count of microseconds from the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of beginning of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`) into an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).  That means up to nine digits of a decimal fraction.

The `Instant` class has handy static methods for converting from a [count of whole seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-), from a [count of whole seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-), or from a [count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-). But unfortunately no such methods for a count of microseconds or nanoseconds.

As a workaround, we can define a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and add it to the epoch reference date already defined as a constant. We can instantiate a `Duration` as a number of nanoseconds. To get nanoseconds, we multiply your microseconds by a thousand. Note the use of 64-bit `long` rather than 32-bit `int`.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( micros * 1_000L );  
Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH.plus( duration );
```

> instant.toString():  2016-09-21T11:24:46.337977Z

Alternatively, you can use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum to convert microseconds to nanoseconds without hard-coding a “magic number”.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos( micros ) );
```

To adjust into other offsets or time zones, search StackOverflow for Java classes `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

## Converting to legacy date-time types

You should avoid the old date-time types bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They have proven to be poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Now supplanted by the java.time types.

But if you must interact with old code not yet updated to the java.time types, you may convert to/from java.time. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

Beware of data loss when converting from a java.time type to [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or `java.util.Calendar`. These types resolve to only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). A truncation from nanoseconds to milliseconds is performed silently, lopping off those last six (of nine) possible digits of a fractional second.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );  // Caution: Data loss in truncating nanoseconds to milliseconds.
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Comment: Interestingly, in your answer the `TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos` is subject to the same problems that `TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toMillis` is. Just in the opposite direction. The `toMillis` conversion may suffer underflow, and in your answer the `toNanos` conversion may suffer overflow. For example if you had `microsecs = Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Why would anyone have a date-time value as a count-from-epoch of `Long.MAX_VALUE` microseconds?

Comment: You left a comment in my answer about possible data loss in my use of `TimeUnit.convert`. I thought it was only fair to highlight that this solution does not solve the problem either. I used `Long.MAX_VALUE` as an example, but you don't need to reach that number to get an overflow. In which scenarios would that make sense? Does it matter? I could ask the same question about the loss of precision in my answer when you highlighted it. But to mention just an example, celestial calculations could easily exceed that number.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo  [Your Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676134/642706) involved truncating nanoseconds to milliseconds. I pointed out the practical issue that that *always* means data-loss (except in the happenstance of zeros). I also pointed out a solution to resolve that problem and improve you example code. Your points about `Long.MAX_VALUE` and celestial calculations are out of bounds of the intentions of the java.time classes, and are delving into the absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code, which will take time stamp as a string:

```
 BigInteger b = new BigInteger("1474457086337977");
 b=b.divide(new BigInteger("1000"));

 String x =b.toString();



DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
System.out.println(milliSeconds);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Or for more accuracy, you can use BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1474457086337977");
b=b.divide(new BigDecimal("1000"));
String x =b.toString();
```

Comment: your milliseconds are too large. give input like:1474717464404

Comment: oh your string is in microseconds.. then convert it into millisec.

Comment: The time is in microseconds not milliseconds.

Comment: @No One, my timestamp string is not in milliseconds but microseconds.