# Convert microseconds to milliseconds without loss of precision and format as date-time in Java

Tags: java, timeunit

How can I convert incoming long time value in `microseconds` into `milliseconds` and then format that to data time stamp as below:

> yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS

I am using Java `SimpleDateFormat` to format the long value to the timestamp. But, converting the microseconds to milliseconds seems problem as I am loosing the value.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

To convert microsecond to millisecond, I am using the TimeUnit:

```
long micro //microseconds
long milli = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(micro, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```

What is the right way to convert the value without loosing any data?

Comment: What's you current input value and what's your expected output value?

Comment: What does you mean with "I am loosing the value"? Can you provide a runnable [mcve], with appropriate sampel values for the microseconds, that shows what you wanted to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: [Convert microseconds string to date in Java or Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675836/convert-microseconds-string-to-date-in-java-or-scala) might help

Comment: You should include sample data, indicating given inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Learn basic Markdown formatting used in Stack Overflow, such as four spaces prefixing lines of code. I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: If `yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS` means three decimals on the seconds, you are going to lose the microsecond precision anyway. So what do you mean that you want? And is there any point in converting to milliseconds first if the end goal is a formatted string?

Comment: uh, you are getting microseconds and want milliseconds without loss of precision. You are aware that 1000 microseconds go into a single millisecond and you're treating the number of milliseconds as an integer value. You are ALWAYS going to lose precision.

Comment: Well, in theory you could keep your milliseconds in a `double`, @jwenting, and probably keep the precision. But that would only complicate getting from there to a formatted date-time string, so no good solution for sure.

Comment: @OleV.V. sure, and he'd need to do just that to retain precision. The code he provides, no matter what he does with his longs, will NEVER retain precision.

Answer (score 8):

> I am using java SimpleDateFormat

**Don’t.**

Avoid the treacherous old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They were supplanted years ago with the *java.time* classes when JSR 310 was adopted.

> convert incoming long time value in [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) into [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond)

**Don’t.**

The *java.time* classes use a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), finer than your microseconds. So no need to throw away data.

### `Instant` = ( whole seconds + fractional second as nanos )

Extract the number of whole seconds.

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds( micros ) ;
```

Get the fractional second, the amount of micros left over after subtracting for the whole seconds.

```
long microsRemaining = 
    micros 
    -
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros( seconds ) 
;
```

Convert the remaining micros to nanos, because the `Instant` class we use next represents a count of whole seconds plus a count of nanoseconds (for the fractional second).

```
long nanos = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos( microsRemaining ) ;
```

Combine the whole seconds with the fractional second in nanos. The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in UTC as a count since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds ).plusNanos( nanos ) ;
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

The `Z` on the end of the string means UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds), and is pronounced `Zulu`.

You can produce strings in your own custom formats using the `DateTimeFormatter` class. [Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern&t=ffab&ia=web) as this has been covered many many many times already.

Tip: Your desired format is so close to the ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ, that **I strongly suggest using the standard format** rather than make up your own cousin of that.

If you wish to see this same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by people of a certain region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunisia" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).